# Swift Package Manager : how to run executableTarget with asynchronous code?

Tags: swift

I am adding a executableTarget to my package and want to run some asynchronous code inside, like this:

```
Task {
    await Test.launch()
}

struct Test {
    static func launch() async {
        let result = await result()
        // ...
    }
}
```

But this code actually never gets called, the program ends before.

What should I do?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming this is top-level code, you should remove the `Task` wrapped around the async call.

```
await Test.launch()

struct Test {
    static func launch() async {
        let result = await result()
        // ...
    }
}
```

This has been supported since [SE-0343 Concurrency in Top-level Code](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0343-top-level-concurrency.md) has been implemented in Swift 5.7.